# Help with the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{s^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \log^{2}(1+ix)\right ) e^{-2\pi nx}dx$

Tags: integration

We have the integral :

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{s^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \log^{2}(1+ix)\right ) e^{-2\pi nx}dx$$

Where s is a complex parameter, and n is a positive integer. The integral converges by virtue of the exponential factor. I tried to deform the path of integration such that we avoid the branch cut(s) of the logarithm. But here is where i got stuck, the internal complex log makes it confusing to do so !

A different version of this problem was posted  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168607/help-with-the-integral-int-0-infty-log-left1-fracs24-pi2-log) with no answers.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? To compute the integral or merely to find an appropriate path?

Comment: i want to compute the integral !

Comment: AFAIK there is no branch cut here. The arguments of both log's have positive imaginary parts.

Comment: In Mathematics Stack Exchange the inner log was not squared. What is the motivation that allow these differences?

Comment: Originally, i wanted to compute the integral with the inner log squared. mistakingly, i dropped the squared sign, and then quickly realised that we can factor the argument of the outer log, and have two integrals without it being there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$I_n(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{s^{2}}{4\pi^{2}} \log^{2}(1+ix)\right ) e^{-2\pi nx}dx$$

a closed-form evaluation of this integral does not look promising, but small and large-$|s|$ asymptotics is doable:

- small $|s|$ (with $\gamma$ Euler's constant and $_3F_3$ the [generalized hypergeometric function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function):

$$I_n(s)=\frac{s^2}{48\pi^3 n}\left(24 i \pi  n \; _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;2 i n \pi )-\tfrac{3}{2} [\pi +2 i \log (2 \pi  n)] [2 i \log (2 \pi  n)+4 i \gamma +\pi ]+6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right)+{\rm order}(|s|^4)$$

- large $|s|$:

$$I_n(s)=\frac{1}{\pi n}\log(s)+{\rm order}(|s|^0)$$

- and for large $n$ the integral decays as $1/n^3$,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^3 I_n(s)=-\frac{s^2}{16\pi^5}$$

Comment: Thanks Carlo ... i am still hoping for an explicit evaluation, regardless of how complicated it looks !